# Unable to define lambda directly in an initializer list that takes a parameter pack and returns a vector<string>

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, variadic

I have the following code that works just fine, to_string function takes in a param pack and returns a vector of string. The lambda defined in the function just transforms each paramer to a string (unpacking happens in the initializer list {}):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename...Args>
auto to_string(const Args& ...params) -> std::vector<std::string>
{
    const auto to_str = [](const auto& p) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << p;
        return ss.str();
    };
    
    return {to_str(params)...};
}

int main()
{
    auto vec = to_string(1, 1.2, 1.5f, "test");
    for (const auto &item : vec)
    {
        std::cout << item << '\n';
    };

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to not have to define the lambda prior to the return call and just use it in the initializer list, something like this (perhaps), but it doesn't work:

```
template <typename...Args>
auto to_string(const Args& ...params) -> std::vector<std::string>
{   
    return {[](const auto& p) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << p;
        return ss.str();
    }()...};
}
```

gcc is saying that lambda should take in the parameter pack which I don't want:

```
test.cpp: In function 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > 
to_string(const Args& ...)':
test.cpp:13:8: error: expansion pattern '<lambda>()' contains no parameter packs
   13 |     }()...};
      |        ^~~
test.cpp:13:11: error: could not convert '{<expression error>}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >'
   13 |     }()...};
      |           ^
      |           |
      |           <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

Comment: the obvious suggestion is to just use the first version, it's easier to read anyway...

Comment: You didn't pass `params` as a parameter to the lambda when you inlined it...

Comment: @M.M Not only is it easier to read, but it's probably faster to compile, as there's only a single lambda type generated rather than one for each parameter

Comment: @Justin That's good enough for an answer I think. [seems to work fine](https://godbolt.org/z/Y3zrbsq7d)

Comment: I totally agree with the comments, but I'm trying to get the syntax right. Any suggestion? Edit: wrote this before Ted answer, which solves it! (and I understand what Justin said along with this answer) Thank you :)

Comment: @bogdan_ariton: "solutions" go in the answer section, not in the question. This is not a webforum; it's OK for you to answer your question, but it needs to go in the right place.

Comment: @NicolBolas, it makes sense, thank you! (it felt that I was being helpful if I made the update)

Comment: it would be helpful if you follow the advice and do post it as answer instead ;) (just make sure to mention Justins comment).

Answer (score 4):

Adding the answer provided by @Justin in the comment section: **Params** needs to be passed to the lambda call:

```
template <typename...Args>
auto to_string(const Args& ...params) -> std::vector<std::string>
{   
    return {[](const auto& p) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << p;
        return ss.str();
    }(params)...};
}
```